# How do I get definitions by hovering over widgets in android studio like Visual Studio Code

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm confused about how to make an android studio behave like VSC. I'm making apps with flutter and dart and have become comfortable with Android Studio. If you hover over a widget/function/whatever, Visual Studio Code gives you a ton of information about the Object.  For instance, in the image, I get a lot of info about the TransactionList variable which is of type List. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPL8S.png)

Comment: In android studio by default, you hold CNTRL(On windows) or CMD(On mac) and hover.

Answer (score 1):

From "Settings">>> "Editor">>> "General">>> Other>>> then check "Show quick documentation on mouse move"

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you have to activate the "Quick Documentation".

You can activate it in:

**"Settings >> Editor >> Code Editing"**

[image]